# Upload pfx to Key Vault using ARM Template

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

is there any way to export .pfx certificate files to a key vault using ARM Templates. I found on github that we can add secrets and even certificates by adding the content-type property and the base64-encoded representation of the certificate. But in my case I would like upload the pfx file.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't exposed to the arm templates yet. You can create secrets, thou. That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you base 64 encode the certificate and then insert it as a secret with the content type application/x-pkcs12 it should work.